# List of shared objects are not listed under list of open files in Linux Kernel

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, virtual-machine, vm-implementation

I am trying to read the list of all open files including the shared objects of a particular program running in VM by using VMI(Virtual Machine Introspection) library. It seems that list of open files of a particular task_struct does not include all the linked shared objects.

Where in kernel, the list of all the shared objects corresponding to a process are stored ? I am guessing that it is stored in one of the kernel data structure otherwise "lsof" will not be able to gather this info.

Answer (score 3):

Relevant info is provided in /proc//maps. Reading sources to find where (and how) this list is taken from is left as an exercise for the reader.